# How to export result to excel from oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

Suppose I have a some selected table result. I want to export it to as a excel file. It can do easily with SQLdeveloper. But I want to know is there anyway to do it in query level.

suppose my table is `MYTABLE`

then selected result set is

```
select * from MYTABLE
```

I want to genarate a excel sheet from above select statment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a XLS(X) file, but CSV (comma-separated-values) will be good enough for Excel to open it. For example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> set colsep ';'
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> spool emp.csv
SQL> select * from emp;
      7369;SMITH     ;CLERK    ;      7902;1980-12-17;       800;          ;        20
      7499;ALLEN     ;SALESMAN ;      7698;1981-02-20;      1600;       300;        30
      7521;WARD      ;SALESMAN ;      7698;1981-02-22;      1250;       500;        30
      7566;JONES     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;1981-04-02;      2975;          ;        20
      7654;MARTIN    ;SALESMAN ;      7698;1981-09-28;      1250;      1400;        30
      7698;BLAKE     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;1981-05-01;      2850;          ;        30
      7782;CLARK     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;1981-06-09;      2450;          ;        10
      7788;SCOTT     ;ANALYST  ;      7566;1982-12-09;      3000;          ;        20
      7839;KING      ;PRESIDENT;          ;1981-11-17;     10000;          ;        10
      7844;TURNER    ;SALESMAN ;      7698;1981-09-08;      1500;         0;        30
      7876;ADAMS     ;CLERK    ;      7788;1983-01-12;      1100;          ;        20
      7900;JAMES     ;CLERK    ;      7698;1981-12-03;       950;          ;        30
      7902;FORD      ;ANALYST  ;      7566;1981-12-03;      3000;          ;        20
      7934;MILLER    ;CLERK    ;      7782;1982-01-23;      1300;          ;        10

14 rows selected.

SQL> spool off;
SQL> $emp.csv
```

"Running" (or "executing") EMP.CSV from the command prompt will, actually, start Excel and open the file.

`SET` set can/should be modified so that the final output looks prettier; the one I posted is really a *quick & dirty* way to do that.